# Zenject Unity3D - Injecting Dependencies from GameObject Hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, zenject

I'm working on a Unity3D project using Zenject for dependency injection. In my project, i have a *UpgradeCardButton* component which is injected with a *ButtonUpgradeCommand* object.

*ButtonUpgradeCommand* is constructed with an object of type *UpgradeCardVisual* and an enum *Enums.UpgradeType*.

*UpgradeCardVisual* object resides in the same transform with the *UpgradeCardButton* object in the hieararchy, and the specific *Enums.UpgradeType* to be injected into the *ButtonUpgradeCommand* can be read from the *UpgradeCardButton* object via an GetUpgradeType() method.

My current implementation currently uses a FromMethod() which looks at the ParentContext and casts that object into a *UpgradeCardButton* and then performs generic operations to access required dependencies.

My question is, my current implementation does not really make sense as resolving these dependencies involve casting objects and using base MonoBehaviour methods, is there a more concise way to get the references to the objects which are required when working with nested dependencies?

Here are the source codes for the files involved:

UpgradesInstaller: This Zenject installer class is responsible for setting up dependency bindings.

```cs
public class UpgradesInstaller : MonoInstaller
    {
        public override void InstallBindings()
        {
            Container.Bind<IUpgradeCommand>().To<ButtonUpgradeCommand>().AsTransient();
            Container.Bind<UpgradeCardVisual>().FromMethod(GetVisualFromButtonUpgrade).AsTransient();
            Container.Bind<Enums.UpgradeType>().FromMethod(GetUpgradeTypeFromButtonUpgrade).AsTransient();
        }

        private UpgradeCardVisual GetVisualFromButtonUpgrade(InjectContext context)
        {
            // Get the UpgradeCardButton component from the context
            UpgradeCardButton upgradeButton = context.ParentContext.ObjectInstance as UpgradeCardButton;

            // Return the UpgradeCardVisual component obtained from the UpgradeCardButton
            return upgradeButton.transform.GetComponent<UpgradeCardVisual>();
        }

        private Enums.UpgradeType GetUpgradeTypeFromButtonUpgrade(InjectContext context)
        {
            // Get the UpgradeCardButton component from the context
            UpgradeCardButton upgradeButton = context.ParentContext.ObjectInstance as UpgradeCardButton;

            // Return the upgradeType obtained from the UpgradeCardButton
            return upgradeButton.GetUpgradeType();
        }
    }
```

ButtonUpgradeCommand: This class represents a command that performs upgrades and requires dependencies injected from UpgradeCardButton.

```cs
public class ButtonUpgradeCommand : IUpgradeCommand
{
        // Injected dependencies
        private UpgradeCardVisual _upgradeVisual;
        private Enums.UpgradeType _upgradeType;

        // Constructor injection
        public ButtonUpgradeCommand(UpgradeCardVisual upgradeVisual, Enums.UpgradeType upgradeType)
        {
            _upgradeVisual = upgradeVisual;
            _upgradeType = upgradeType;
        }

        // Methods and logic for upgrades...
}
```

UpgradeCardButton: This MonoBehaviour represents a button that triggers an upgrade action. It also contains dependencies to be injected into ButtonUpgradeCommand.

```cs
    public class UpgradeCardButton : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField] Enums.UpgradeType _upgradeType;
        private IUpgradeCommand _upgradeCommand;
        private IUpgradeCommand _checkCanBuyCommand;

        // Constructor injection
        [Inject]
        public void Construct(IUpgradeCommand upgradeCommand)
        {
            _upgradeCommand = upgradeCommand;
        }

        public Enums.UpgradeType GetUpgradeType() => _upgradeType;

        // Methods and logic for upgrade button behavior...
    }
```

I am wondering if there is a more concise and efficient way to bind dependencies via using Zenject.